# Stack Snippet console styles can be overriden

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

While editing [a post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/266019/120114) I put the code into a runnable Stack Snippet and noticed that the styles affected the console:

```js
console.log('good luck reading this when the console wrapper dimensions are fixed to 60x60 pixels!');
const wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('as-console-wrapper');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => wrappers[0].classList.toggle('w-100'));
```

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle console width</button>
```

Can this be prevented? Perhaps by adjusting the HTML or adding `width: 100% !important` to the styles for `<div class="as-console-wrapper">`?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent this?

Comment: @Makoto The console isn't really part of what is being presented in the snippet - it would analogous to a webpage affecting the display of the browser console

Comment: This has been reported before: [Snippet CSS content is corrupting the console display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308959/snippet-css-content-is-corrupting-the-console-display) And on MSO as well: [Sandbox the console separately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339480)